# how to replace the data array in JTable

Tags: java, object, multidimensional-array, jtable, refresh

I have a JTable and I want to be able to put a completely new data 2D array in it. is there a way to accomplise this? I used a AbstractTableModel before but than I can't acces the selected cell so I could make them clickable.

thanks

Comment: Either, set the new data on the `DefaultTableModel` or set a new `TableModel` on the `JTable`.

Comment: I get an error that I cant cast a jtable to tableModle

Comment: That's probably because a `JTable` isn't a `TableModel`. It's a `JTable`.

Comment: Yes but I used 
<code>JTable tableTemp = new JTable(data,columnNames);
DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) tableTemp.getModel();
table.setModel(tableModel);</code>